# Best practice for running multiple PHP processes using PDO objects?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, pdo

I'm running 100 PHP scripts simultaneously on a Linux machine with MySQL.
I'm using PDO, with the ATTR_PERSISTENT parameter set to false. Process typically execute a few SQL commands and sleeps for 30 seconds.

Looking at the process list using top, I see a lot of mysqld processes, each taking a substantial amount of memory space.

I understand this problem can be solved by redesigning, to use queues and\or shared connections, but I'm looking for a temporary fix until I'm ready with a better setup.

What will be the best remedy for handling such a setup?
Should I destroy and recreate each PDO object while the process sleeps?
Am I missing some basic configuration option either in PDO, or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of PDO and sleeping, if you do not plan on re-using the connection, kill it as early as you can. The reason being is that, while it is sleeping (for nothing, effectively), the worker thread on MySQL is still in existence.

If you are **NOT** going to waste the sleeping processes, I recommend going for a persistent connection and to share it between PHP processes. This, however, opens a new can of worms: deadlocks.

The best way to close the connection is to destroy the PDO object - i.e. `$yourPDOOBject = null`.

Comment: How would I go about sharing the connections, and avoid deadlocks?

Comment: Just set the PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT parameter to true. From there, assuming you use exactly the same credentials to connect, PDO will do the rest for connection sharing. For deadlocks, you need to be aware of how MySQL locks rows/tables depending on what is running. Look up "MySQL locking" for the ENGINE you're using for your tables, as they do it differently.